# Discord Bot reads Google Sheets and returns values in table. I'd like to return values ar CSV in a message without the table formatting

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, google-sheets-api

Hi I have a bot that I am trying to modify...

It currently displays the data in a table, but I would like it displayed as CSV in a message.

Is there a way to do this?

**The data currently displays like this:**

╔═════════════════════╤═════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ Names               │ Grd │ Val1  │  Val  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ a   │ 400K  │ 469K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ b   │ 392K  │ 427K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 392K  │ 455K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 385K  │ 394K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 366K  │ 445K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 363K  │ 397K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ a   │ 362K  │ 433K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ a   │ 362K  │ 400K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 358K  │ 426K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 356K  │ 429K  ║
╟─────────────────────┼─────┼───────┼───────╢
║ tom bob jan tim tom │ U   │ 354K  │ 409K  ║
╚═════════════════════╧═════╧═══════╧═══════╝

**I would like it to display like this:**

Names,Grade, Value1,Value2
tom bob jan tim tom,a,400K,469K
tom bob jan tim tom,b,392K,427K
tom bob jan tim tom,U,392K,455K
tom bob jan tim tom,U,354K,409K

Thanks in advance

The .js code is below.

````
const config = require('../util/globals');
const { table } = require('table');
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');

const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(config.SHEET_ID);
doc.useServiceAccountAuth(require('../client-secret.json'));

module.exports = {
  command: 'list',
  aliases: ['le'],
  dm: false,
  permissions: (member) => {
    return true;
  },
  async execute(bot, msg, args) {
    const abbreviations = fs
      .readFileSync('heroes.txt', 'utf-8')
      .split(/\r\n|\n/g)
      .map((row) => row.split(':')[0].toLowerCase());
    if (args.length < 4) {
      return msg.channel.send('Please at least enter 4 names.');
    }
    if (args.slice(0, 5).some((arg) => !abbreviations.includes(arg))) {
      return msg.channel.send('Unrecognised name(s). Please use all lowercase');
    }

    await doc.loadInfo();

    const sheet = doc.sheetsByTitle['Output'];
    await sheet.loadCells();

    sheet.getCellByA1('H3').value = args.slice(0, 5).join(' ');
    await sheet.saveUpdatedCells();

    const sheet2 = doc.sheetsByTitle['OutputI'];

    await sheet2.loadCells();
    const data1 = [
      [
        'Names',
        'Grd',
        'Value1',
        'value2',
      ],
      ...[...Array(15).keys()].slice(9).map((row) => {
        return [...Array(4).keys()].map(
          (column) => sheet2.getCell(row, column).value
        );
      })
    ];

    const data2 = [
      [
        'Names',
        'Grd',
        'Value1',
        'value2',
      ],
      ...[...Array(20).keys()].slice(15).map((row) => {
        return [...Array(4).keys()].map(
          (column) => sheet2.getCell(row, column).value
        );
      })
    ];

    msg.channel.send(
      '```' + table(data1).split('\n').slice(0, -2).join('\n') + '```'
    );
    msg.channel.send(
      '```' + table(data2).split('\n').slice(2).join('\n') + '```'
    );
  }
};
````

Answer (score 3):

I figured this out.  Kinda feel dumb for even asking...

````
msg.channel.send(
  '```' + table(data1).split('\n').slice(0, -2).join('\n') + '```'
);
msg.channel.send(
  '```' + table(data2).split('\n').slice(2).join('\n') + '```'
````

just had to change the above lines to:

```
msg.channel.send(
  (data1)
);
msg.channel.send(
  (data2)
```